# How to set a "formula triangle" in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, latexit

I'd like to typeset a formula triangle ("Formeldreieck") for the `U=E*d` formula - is there an easy way of doing this within LaTeX (I actually use LaTeXit on Mac OS X, but I do know how to add packages if necessary)?

Comment: you mean like [this](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/FormulaOhm02.gif) ?

Comment: Exactly - see Marco's answer below (for which I am very thankful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use TikZ for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
    Formeldreieck/.style={
        draw=blue,thick,
        regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=3,
        node distance=2cm,
    }
}
\begin{document}
\tikz\node[Formeldreieck]{$\dfrac{U}{R\cdot I}$};
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this post is ancient, but it was the first result on Google.
No offense, but I found that gigantic triangle with the small equation inside not quite satisfactory, so I made my own and am sharing it for anyone who is sent here by Google, too. (And I'm aware this likely isn't the most elegant solution either, I'm grateful for any suggestions/improvements!)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\formulatriang}[7][.33]{
    % optional first argument PW: variables will be placed on the angle
    % bisectors, PW of the way between vertex and opposite side.
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=3.5em,y=3.5em]
    \def\pw{#1}
    \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (60:1);
    \coordinate (C) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (AB) at ($ (A)!.5!(B)$);
    \coordinate (AC) at ($ (A)!.5!(C)$);
    \coordinate (a) at ($ (60:1)!\pw!(.5,0)$);
    \coordinate (b) at ($ (0,0)!\pw!(30:0.866)$);
    \coordinate (c) at ($ (1,0)!\pw!(60:0.5) $);
    \draw[style=thick,rounded corners=.5ex]
    (A) node[anchor=south,rotate=-60] {#3}
    -- 
    (B) node[anchor=south,rotate=60] {#5}
    --
    (C) node[anchor=north,rotate=0] {#7}
    -- cycle;       
    \draw  (AB) -- ($ (AB)!.2!(C)$);
    \draw  (AC) -- ($ (AC)!.2!(B)$);
    \node at ($(b)!.5!(c)$) {$\cdot$};
    \path 
    (a) node[shape=circle,anchor=center] {#2}
    --
    (b) node[shape=circle,anchor=center] {#4}
    --
    (c)
    node[shape=circle,anchor=center] {#6}
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}
    A smaller one \formulatriang{$m$}{mass}{$\rho$}{density}{$V$}{volume}.
    
    But since I used em units, it should look fine with a larger font, too:\\
    \Huge
    \formulatriang[.4]{$F$}{force}{$\sigma$}{stress}{$A$}{area}
\end{document}
```

[image]